# configure puma through rails command line

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, puma

I want to be able to launch the rails server so that puma is configured to use ssl.

```
rails s puma -b 127.0.0.1
```

works to bind it to an address  and

```
puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=/Users/bobby/.ssh/server.key&cert=/Users/bobby/.ssh/server.crt'
```

works to launch puma using SSL and my self signed certificate.

But i cannot find a way to include the SSL binding on the rails command line.  Any help out there

when i try to combine them i get

```
rails s puma -b 'ssl://127.0.0.1:3000?key=/Users/bobby/.ssh/server.key&cert=/Users/bobby/.ssh/server.crt'
```

getaddrinfo: nodename nor servname provided

Comment: having same issue, are you able to solve it ?

Comment: no i gave up on it and use my staging server to test

Comment: I am currently using phusion passenger and it works like charm, let me know if you need help regarding setting SSL for passenger server.